# PHP multiple-connection socket (broadcasting issue)

Tags: php, sockets

What I'm trying to achieve is a socket server that broadcasts some data to all connected peers. This is code of server loop:

```
while(TRUE) {
    $read = array();

    $read[] = $socket;

    for($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++) {
        if($client_sockets[$i] != NULL) {
            $read[$i+1] = $client_sockets[$i];
        }
    }

    #This is broadcasting loop
    foreach($client_sockets as $send_sock)
    {
        socket_write($send_sock, "broadcasting".PHP_EOL);
    }

    if( socket_select($read, $write, $except, NULL) === FALSE ) {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
        die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
    }

    if( in_array($socket, $read) ) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $max_clients; $i++) {
            if($client_sockets[$i] == NULL) {
                $client_sockets[$i] = socket_accept($socket);

                if( socket_getpeername($client_sockets[$i], $client_address, $client_port) ) {
                    echo "Client $client_address : $client_port is now connected to us. \n";
                }

                $message = "Connected to php socket server".PHP_EOL;
                socket_write($client_sockets[$i], $message);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine, accepts multiple connections and broadcasts data, except for one moment: loop starts only after I type any input from any connected client via telnet. I know this is because `socket_select` waits for this input, but I don't know how to start broadcasting right after client is connected.

Appreciate any help on this, because I've got feeling that I'm terribly wrong somewhere.

Comment: You should post your update as an answer and accept yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Selfown answer**

Problem indeed was in `socket_select($read, $write, $except, NULL)`; and not actually a problem. Last `NULL` parameter starts endless block, awaiting for client response; to make script work properly, I've changed this timeout, so it looks looks this: `socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0, 500000)`. On the client side, however, parameter should be set to `NULL`(**NOT** `0`!), so script remains idle while waiting for server broadcasting message.

I've also discovered that such blocking behavior is similar to to `socket_read()` and `socket_write()` functions, which endless by default; to change it, use `socket_set_option`:

```
socket_set_option($master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array("sec" => 0, "usec" => 1000));
socket_set_option($master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array("sec" => 0, "usec" => 1000));
```

And 1000 microseconds is as low as I could get.

Actually, I've updated answer for somebody who voted up; but I hope that solution will be useful anyway.